# Is there any functionality similar to ViewHolder in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm doing a PhoneGap Android project as a learning experience.

I want to implement a *SwipeView* dynamically according to the length of a specific column, and my doubts are:

1) can you take the length of a specific column? As we implement it by the following code:

```
var a = results.rows.length;
```

I'm unable to add something like the following

```
var a = results.COLUMN_NAME.length;
```

2) I want to implement a *SwipeView* dynamically based on the length of the records in the database.

I'm thinking about using *ViewHolder*m how we do in Android, such as

```
mSwipeView.addView(holder.getView(j));

public class ViewHolder { ... }
```

Is this correct? Is there any  functionality similar to *ViewHolder* in JavaScript?

Answer (score -1):

I think ViewHolder in Javascript should keep references to DOM elements so that You don't have to query for it.

For example if you have traversable list, and each item is something like a div element (or anything else) with the class item_0...item_n (or any other attribute), our view holder should hold references to those elements like:

```
var viewHolder = [];
viewHolder[0] = document.querySelector('item_0');
...
viewHolder[n] = document.querySelector('item_n');
```

Then if You need to reference those elements, for example to set text property or anything else, you would do it with the holder rather then constantly querying the DOM:

```
viewHolder[n].text = "Some text";
```

Of course our view holder should be more object oriented then in my example which is just for demonstration purpose.

P.S. Do not forget to "nullify" viewHolder otherwise you will probably have memory leaks cause there are still variables linked to DOM objects.